# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR::XML_Parser() in /[DIR]/php5.6.10/lib/php/PEAR.php on line 219

Tags: php, pear

After doing a lot of Google search and also going trough SO questions.

I did not find solution to this problem.

I have installed MAMP with multiple versions.

Currently working on PHP-5.6.10.

I am facing this issue:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR::XML_Parser() in /[DIR]/php5.6.10/lib/php/PEAR.php on line 219
```

Can anybody please look into it?

Comment: Do you need to install / enable an extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved.

How?

It was a version problem.

Go to http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Parser/download

Click on `Download`, you will get the appropriate package name.

Install package with that version.

**EDIT:**

Uninstalled and reinstalled the module

`XML_Parser`

Commands:

`pear uninstall XML_Parser-1.3.7`

`pear install XML_Parser-1.3.1`